# SOAP Class with Collection Property

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, soap

Is it possible to pass a collection of items as a property in a soap reference?

I have a class that I am using as the data source of a report, I want to be able to pass the header Items with a collection of detail items to the report. I have setup the following class and method, the method returns the header details but the collection of items is not sent to the client.

```
public class PriceHeader
{
    [Key]
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}

[Query(IsComposable = false)]
public IEnumerable<PriceHeader> GetPriceHeaders()
{
    return this.DataContext.Prices.Select(i => new PriceHeader()
    {
        Desc = i.Description,

        Items = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Item>(i.LinkedItems.Select(rc => new Item()
        {
            Field = rc.FieldName,
            Value1 = rc.Value,
            Value2 = rc.Value2
        }))
    });
}
```

I'm using Siverlight with WCF and the report class is linking to the WCF service with a soap client.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce the problem, i.e. I could pass a collection of items to the client from the service. Are you absolutely sure that your linq fills the Items list in your PriceHeader objects properly? My guess is that you return a collection of PriceHeader objects to the client whose Items property are always empty lists...

Here's what I tried:

Service side:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    IEnumerable<PriceHeader> GetData();
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public IEnumerable<PriceHeader> GetData()
    {
        return PriceHeader.GetPriceHeaders();
    }
}

public class PriceHeader
{
    public string Desc { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<PriceHeader> GetPriceHeaders()
    {
        var list = new List<PriceHeader>
        {
            new PriceHeader(){Desc = "Desc1", Items=new ObservableCollection<Item>{new Item(){Field = "field1", Value1 = "val11", Value2 = "val21"}}},
            new PriceHeader(){Desc = "Desc2", Items=new ObservableCollection<Item>{new Item(){Field = "field2", Value1 = "val12", Value2 = "val22"}}}
        };

        return list;
    }
}
```

Client side:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var client = new Service1Client();
    client.GetDataCompleted += client_GetDataCompleted;
    client.GetDataAsync();

}

private void client_GetDataCompleted(object sender, GetDataCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //here I inspected the results and even the Items property of PriceHeader objects were properly filled
    var results = e.Result as IEnumerable<PriceHeader>;

    //not sure if this is necessary here
    (sender as Service1Client).CloseAsync();
}
```

It was interesting to observe that there's no need to decorate PriceHeader and its properties with DataContract and DataMember attributes (respectively) as the service proxy generation does that automatically..

Comment: Hi Sorry been very busy I will mark this as an answer as it helped, I was originally passing an entity created with Telerik OpenAccess, This wouldnt pass a collection through as a property. I have now added a Data Contract and convert the entity to the DataContract pass that with the collection property and the data comes through